# How do I add custom items to the context menu in Dolphin in KDE 5?

Tags: scripts, kubuntu, kde, customization, dolphin

I've Googled around, but can't seem to find any consistent tutorials or documentation that describe how to do this (in my case, on Kubuntu 15.10).  I want to add custom scripts to the context menu in Dolphin (a la `nautilus-scripts` for Nautilus).  For some reason, when I follow any instructions I find, I'm only able to make the context menu appear when right-clicking the relevant `.desktop` file.  **How can I solve this?**

Answer (score 25):

**KDE Service Menus**

> In KDE-speak a "servicemenu" is a special entry that appears in a
> context menu (or other context-based interface) for a file (or for
> directory), depending on the type of files that are selected.

Service Menus with Dolphin:

- https://develop.kde.org/docs/dolphin/service-menus/
- https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?25740-Service-Menus-with-Dolphin

  - --> KF5 Service Menus: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?25740-Service-Menus-with-Dolphin&p=367207&viewfull=1#post367207

Service Menus Missing: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=223&t=128621

**Paths**

KDE Frameworks 5 is looking services from:

```
kf5-config --path services
```

Executing:

```
$ kf5-config --path services
/home/user26687/.local/share/kservices5/:/usr/share/kservices5/
```

That is:

User servicemenus are:

```
$HOME/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/
```

System servicemenus are at

```
/usr/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/
```

**Desktop files**

Servicemenus are defined using .desktop files. Desktop Entry Specification: https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/

[image: Image: Desktop Entry Specification has the meaning of the keys/codes]
Image: Sample of the Desktop Entry Specification keys/codes

**An example - simple servicemenu with file path:**

Making: $HOME/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/myFirstServiceMenu.desktop

If the directory doesn't exist the user can make it !

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
Icon=smiley-shape
X-KDE-ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
MimeType=all/allfiles;
Actions=helloWorld;
Encoding=UTF-8

[Desktop Action helloWorld]
Name=Hello with path information
Icon=smiley-shape
Exec=kdialog --msgbox "Path is %f"
```

[image: Image: a servicemenu at the right place.]
Image: a servicemenu at the right place.

Closing all Dolphin windows and starting a new one. When right clicking a file:

[image: Image: sample of the servicemenu action]

Comment: Please add the relevant part of the answer here and provide the links only for reference.

Comment: If you are editing the service action while you configure it, you may need to (1) delete the service.desktop file (keeping it open in your editor), (2) open and close dolphin so that it thinks that the service disappeared, (3) recreate the new service file by saving it, (4) reopen dolphin.

Comment: Seems the desktop files can't start with a number.

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04

place the scripts in the directory `~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/`

run `kbuildsycoca5`

scripts will be visible in new dolphin instances.

Comment: I tried this even prior to placing my scripts directory in there an error: `The menu spec file contains a Layout or DefaultLayout tag without the mandatory Merge tag inside`. I was hoping to dump a folder with about 100 bash shell scripts I wrote and get to them from the menu. Not keen to make make a .desktop file for 100 .sh files is all. I wonder if I can put a folder into the menus?

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 16.04 with KDE (Kubuntu) one appropriate directory for **.desktop* files is `/usr/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/`

(compare the output of `dpkg -L ark` to find similar file locations concerning the ark submenus)