# KDE Service Menus get list of selected files

Tags: scripts, kde, kde5

I'm a Gnome user and I'm trying KDE 5. When I was using Nautilus (Gnome), I had a bunch of shell script actions that worked on a list of selected file paths given by the variable `$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS`.

[Reading this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719262/how-do-i-add-custom-items-to-the-context-menu-in-dolphin-in-kde-5), I am aware that Dolphin actions provide the code `%F: A list of files. Use for apps that can open several local files at once. Each file is passed as a separate argument to the executable program`.

The problem is that ***Each file is passed as a separate argument to the executable program***, while my scripts are designed to work with the variable $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS.

Ideally, I would like to reuse my old scripts. Is it possible to convert the Dolphin's `%F` list and set it as the variable `$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` for my scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get access to all the arguments passed to a script using `$@` in bash, this means technically you can create a wrapper script that first prepares a fake environment variable like this:

```
 export NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS=$@
 ./real-script.sh
```

Of course you can also simply modify your script to use `$@` like this if you want instead of the original nautilus variable:

```
for var in "$@"
do
    echo "x" "$var"
done
```

Also note in your `.desktop` file for ServiceMenus you'll want to do something like:

```
Exec=script %F
```

Notice that `%F` doesn't have quotes around it.

Comment: I'm also struggling to get my Nautilus scripts to work in Dolphin service menus. Can you explain to this learner why this magical *"$@"* has to be modified (at least sometimes) like this: `for filename in "${@}"; do convert "$filename" "${filename%.*}.jpg"; done`.