# Copy/paste script for Dolphin's context menu using rsync?

Tags: rsync, copy, dolphin, copy-and-paste

Does anyone know a script or has an idea how to make a script which is using rsync to copy/paste files? The script should work like the normal copy/paste routine in dolphin but using rsync instead.
Such a script would be nice because rsync's incremental functions are pretty good and very reliable.

Comment: This: https://askubuntu.com/questions/719262/how-do-i-add-custom-items-to-the-context-menu-in-dolphin-in-kde-5 should give you a starting point.

Comment: Thabks for your answer but the question is not really about the servicemenu and the implementation of the script. It is more about the script itself....