# Why does "MimeType=text/x-shellscript;" not work in this .desktop file?

Tags: kubuntu, plasma-5, mime-type

OS: Kubuntu 18.04

The default file manager, dolphin, has the facility to use Service Menus, somewhat like Custom Actions in thunar and pcmanfm or Nautilus Actions.

Quoting from [here](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Creating_Konqueror_Service_Menus):

> In KDE-speak a "servicemenu" is a special entry that appears in a
>   context menu (or other context-based interface) for a file (or for
>   directory), depending on the type of files that are selected.

More information is available [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/719262/248158).

---

To learn a bit more about this facility made my own Service Menu called "Open with Kate", ~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/open-file.desktop, which I want to use to view and edit scripts in my *~/bin* folder when in Dolphin.

```
[Desktop Action open-file]
Exec=kate "%U"
Name=Open with Kate
Icon=document-open

[Desktop Entry]
Actions=open-file

#Works
#MimeType=all/all

#Works
MimeType=text/plain;

#Doesn't work
#MimeType=text/x-shellscript;

ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
Type=Service
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel
```

If I use `MimeType=all/all` or `MimeType=text/plain;` the service menu is functional. An "Open with Kate" entry is present and functional:

[image: Open with Kate is seen]

But I wondered if I could narrow the scope of this menu by changing the MimeType from `all/all` or `text/plain` to something more appropriate.

```
$ file --mime timestamp.sh
timestamp.sh: text/x-shellscript; charset=us-ascii
$
```

So I tried using `MimeType=text/x-shellscript;` hoping that the "Open with Kate" entry would appear when I right-clicked on plain text files or scripts but result is that the "Open with Kate" entry just disappears:

[image: Open with Kate is absent]

But `x-shellscript` is present in at least one *.desktop* file on my system, *vim.desktop* (towards the end of grep's output):

```
$ grep -i shellscript /usr/share/applications/*.desktop
/usr/share/applications/vim.desktop:MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
$
```

So why doesn't `MimeType=text/x-shellscript;` work in the context of "Open with Kate"?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but since `.desktop` files are related to xdg, you may need to use a mime type known to `xdg-mime`. In my installation (Kubuntu 18.04), `text/x-shellscript` is unknown, but `xdg-mime query filetype test.sh` on a simple shell script returns `application/x-shellscript` as mime type, maybe try that?

Comment: I tried and it works perfectly. Please post an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you found in your `vim.desktop` file, there is a subtype called `x-shellscript`. However, its type is not `text` but `application`, i.e. `application/x-shellscript`.

Although "MIME type" is not available as a column in Dolphin (as opposed to e.g. Thunar), the MIME type is displayed in some dialogs, e.g. when you right-click a file and select "Open With..." (Next to the "Remember association..." check box at the bottom) and in the properties dialog when you select "File Type Options" (at the very top).

The reason why `file` reported a different MIME type is that it uses a different database. Most popular desktop environments nowadays more or less adhere to the [freedesktop.org](https://www.freedesktop.org/) (formerly known as X Desktop Group, XDG) specifications which include [Desktop entries](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktop-entry-spec/) and [Shared MIME database](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/shared-mime-info-spec/). To find the MIME type according to that database, you can use the `xdg-mime` tool from `xdg-utils`:

```
xdg-mime query filetype [file]
```