# Add item into context menu in Dolphin

Tags: kubuntu, dolphin, plasma-5, context-menu

Is it possible to add new items into context menu in Dolphin (KDE Plasma) if I right click on something?

I would like to make a script called *Move to applications*, which will show **only** if I right click on a *.desktop* file and then it will move it to */usr/share/applications/* folder. Or is there a faster way for moving *.desktop* files to */usr/share/applications/* folder.

Comment: @DKBose because it is boring and it takes several times longer than 1-click from context menu

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create a [Service Menu](https://askubuntu.com/q/719262/248158) to do what you want.

- Create the folder *~/.local/share/kservices5*
- Create the folder *~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus*
- In *~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus* create a plain text file called *move.desktop*

Paste the following content into *move.desktop*

```
[Desktop Action move-file]

Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5/kdesu mv "%U" /usr/share/applications

Name=Move file
Icon=document-send

[Desktop Entry]
Actions=move-file

MimeType=application/x-desktop;

ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
Type=Service
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel
```

The use of `MimeType=application/x-desktop;` ensures that this context menu entry will be seen only when the target file is a *.desktop* file.

This is an image of Dolphin's context menu *before* creating the service menu:

[image: Dolphin context menu before creating the service menu]

In the following screenshot taken *after* creating the service menu you'll see an additional entry, *Move file*:

[image: Note the Move file entry]

Clicking on *Move file* will prompt you for your password because you want to move a file into */usr/share/applications*.

[image: Password required]

After providing your password, the selected file will be moved to */usr/share/applications*:

[image: File is now removed from its original location and is now in */usr/share/applications*]

Note that the owner isn't the same as .desktop files already there. You'll need to fix that however you choose:

[image: File ownership differs]

---

In case you need to change ownership/permissions, you could modify the `Exec=` line like this (to change ownership):

```
Exec=printf %U | xsel -b -i && /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5/kdesu mv "%U" /usr/share/applications && cd /usr/share/applications && /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5/kdesu chown root:root $( basename $(xsel -b -o) )
```

The additional steps involve using *printf* and *xsel* to put the path of the file into the clipboard and then using *basename* to strip off everything but the filename. Of course, you'll need `kdesu` again! I don't know if there's a shorter way!

Comment: If someone is still using Dolphin from KDE4 for whatever reason, the path to directory to create the desktop-file in is `~/.kde/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus`.

Answer (score 1):

Under KDE Plasma, the simplest solution may be to add a new "open with" entry. To do so, go to <kbd>Configure Desktop</kbd> (`systemsettings5`) > <kbd>Applications</kbd> > <kbd>File Associations</kbd>.

Then choose the relevant file type using the search field; It will give results both for mimetype names and file extension filters. Typing `.kdelnk` or `.desktop` will bring up the mime-type `application/x-desktop`.

In the panel `Application Preference Order`, click the button <kbd>+ Add</kbd> to configure the new program. By default new entries are chosen as the default program; You will want to move the script to a more suitable position in the order.