# Kubuntu 19.10: Ark can't open some zip files

Tags: kubuntu, archive, ark

Ark seems to be having problems with opening some zip files.

For instance, when I try to open zip files exported from https://beefree.io/ I get this error:

> Ark wasn't able to open XX. No suitable plugin found. Ark doesn't seem to  support  this file type.

`inxi` output:

```
Kernel: 5.3.0-40-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.18.2 
           Distro: Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine) 
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: INTEL model: H110 serial: <filter> UEFI [Legacy]: American Megatrends v: 5.12 date: 09/11/2017 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i3-6100 bits: 64 type: MT MCP L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
           Speed: 900 MHz min/max: 800/3700 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 900 2: 900 3: 900 4: 900 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 530 driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.5 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2) v: 4.5 Mesa 19.2.8 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Family HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.3.0-40-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter driver: ath9k 
           IF: wlp1s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet driver: r8169 
           IF: enp2s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
```

I have already added KDE PPA and set locale to `RU`.
I have Ark modules (Bzip2, Gzip, Info-zip, Libarchive, Libzip, LZMA, P7zip, RAR, Unarchiver) installed:

However, I can open the same archive files in Ark in Ubuntu 19.10 (GNOME), but it fails in Kubuntu 19.10+PPA (KDE)

What could be the issue here?

Comment: #2 doesn't say that.

It says that I could open the same archive using Ark in UBUNTU 19.10(gnome), not in Kubuntu 19.10 (kde)

Comment: Please, read the whole sentence (see above)

Comment: The post title literally specifies that the problem happens in Kubuntu 19.10 (which uses kde), not Ubuntu `19.10 (which uses gnome). it works fine in default ubuntu 19.10 (gnome)

I either click on the file, select Open with Ark or double-click it.

Comment: **DK Bose**

I meant ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports

**Grya**

Hmm it's strange it didn't work in Bungie. 

Meanwhile I had to enable dolphin to open archives as folders as a workaround.

Comment: @DKBose I've shared archive example in my answer.

Comment: @DKBose

hey, you can just go to the site mentioned in the first post,press start designing and select a template. then export it to zip.  I also uploaded a sample zip file here https://www59.zippyshare.com/v/0c0uLqzb/file.html

Answer (score 1):

I tried to open it from Dolphin, Nemo, PCmanFM, Thunar using Arc and error appears.

But there's no error while trying to open this zip file using Engrampa archive manager.

Plugins that are installed and enabled in arc are: Bzip2, Gzip, Info-zip, Libarchive, Libzip, LZMA, P7zip, RAR, The Unarchiver

Other zip archives could be opened by Arc. But not this one.

It seems this file has a little different structure Arc could not understand.

As a temporary solution, as you said, Dolphin could be used to open archives as folders or engrampa archive manager could be used instead of Arc:

```
$ sudo apt install engrampa
```

[File example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pY5G4D0EWMGpGpuUQXZ-pWCkSrFP7FIS/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unzip` which should be present on your system by default.

In `konsole`, simply run `unzip beefree-n1koo8f6b3.zip` for example.

To do so in Dolphin,

- Right-click on the file
- Choose "Open With …", not "Open with Ark"
- In the window that appears, just type `unzip` in the text box where the insertion cursor already is
- If you need to open such files frequently, check the box next to Remember application association …
- In *Terminal options*, choose what you prefer
- Click OK

[image: using unzip in Dolphin]

---

Another route is to make your own [Service Menu](https://askubuntu.com/q/719262/248158). Create `~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus` if it doesn't exist and in the `ServiceMenus` folder have a file with the following content:

```
[Desktop Action extract-with-unzip]
Exec=unzip "%U"
Name=Extract with unzip
Icon=archive-extract

[Desktop Entry]
Actions=extract-with-unzip

MimeType=application/zip;

ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
Type=Service
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel
```

Save it as `unzip.desktop` or something else but it must have a `.desktop` suffix.

Now, whenever you have a `.zip` file, you can right-click on it and choose "Open with Ark" *or* with "Extract with unzip":

[image: Make your own Service Menu]

Answer (score 0):

First you should try to install

```
sudo apt install -y p7zip-full p7zip-rar
```

If this still doesn't help, install **file-roller** and configure it for zip manipulations. (KUbuntu 20.04)

From command line do a

```
sudo apt install file-roller
```

and afterwards open the `File Associations` app  and enter following set-up for `zip` :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to this discussion, but this seems to be the first link on Google when searching for ways of resolving this error. What seems to have done it for me was installing `unrar` - Ark can now open .rar files with absolutely no issue.

Comment: It seems the OP was about ZIP files, so I don't see what it has to do with `unrar`.